# cómo obtener dataURI() de react-apexchart?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de obtener el dataURI() de react-apexchart, por lo que he probado, con apexchart, no hay problema con obtener el dataURI, pero con la integración con react, me genera problema...

Ejemplo:

```js
import ReactApexCharts from 'react-apexcharts'

------------------
 this.state = {
      options: {
        chart: {id: 'chartDonuts'},
        labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        tooltip: {enabled: false},
        noData: {
          text: 'No se encontraron datos',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          style: {
            color: 'rgb(126, 126, 126)',
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontFamily: undefined,
          },
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            customScale: 1,
            expandOnClick: true,
            offsetX: -40,
            offsetY: 0,
            donut: {
              size: '60%',
              labels: {
                show: true,
                total: {
                  show: true,
                  label: 'Total',
                  formatter: function(w) {
                    return (
                      w.globals.seriesTotals
                        .reduce((a, b) => {
                          return a + b
                        }, 0)
                        .toFixed(2) + 'h'
                    )
                  },
                },
                value: {
                  show: true,
                  formatter: function(val) {
                    return val + 'h'
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
        },
      },
      series: [1,2,3],
    }
    
-------------

 <ReactApexCharts
   options={this.state.options}
   series={this.state.series}
   type='donut'
   width='380'
  />
```

El código anterior funciona bien, el problema comienza al querer obtener el datURI del gráfico generado...

Según apexcharts debería ser:

```js
var chart = new ApexCharts(elemento, options);
var dataURL = chart.dataURI().then((uri) => {
  ....
})
```

https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#dataURI

Si alguien sabe como integrarlo con react-apexchart, se lo agradecería mucho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba usando `ref` en el componente para obtener el componente ya renderizado si estas usando clases o `useRef` si estas usando hooks

```
<ReactApexCharts
   options={this.state.options}
   series={this.state.series}
   type='donut'
   width='380'
   ref={this.chart}
/>
```

y para ejecutar el `dataURI()` tendrías que ponerlo en algún tipo de evento

```
this.chart.dataURI().then((uri) => {
  console.log(uri)
})
```

Comment: Hola Victor, muchísimas gracias... En verdad soy bastante nuevo con React, pero con la guía que me diste, me funcionó...

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado, te pido que si te funciono marques la respuesta como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al final deje el código así:

```html
<ReactApexCharts
  options={this.state.options}
  series={this.state.series}
  type='donut'
  width='380'
  ref={this.chart}
/>


<IconButton
  color='primary'
  className={classes.button}
  aria-label='Obtener PDF'
  size='medium'
  onClick={this.getPDF}
>
  <Icono />
</IconButton>
```

```js
chart = (e) => {
    this.setState({componentChart: e})
  }
  
getPDF = () => {
  this.state.componentChart.chart.dataURI().then((uri) => {
    console.log('URI::', uri)
    var pdf = new jsPDF()
    pdf.addImage(uri, 'PNG', 0, 0)
    pdf.save('download.pdf')
  })
}
```

Muchas gracias Victor por la ayuda!!